# RestKit Post Request Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, http-post, restkit

Hi I'm trying to post NSManagedObject to the server using Rest Kit. Could somebody take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

This is my json structure for post request which I tested by using RubyMine REST client and it posted object properly:

```
 {  
       "name":"test name",
       "mobile":"22334455",
       "dob":"1989-12-12",
       "medications":"test",
       "medical_conditions":"",
       "watch":
        {
            "phonewatchno":"123789",
            "latitude":-33.99,
            "longitude":151.11,
            "gmaps":null,
            "battery_life":null,
            "last_update_time":null,
            "location":"",
            "short_imei":null,
            "rssi":null,
            "charging_status":null,
            "voltage":null,
            "network":null,
            "altitude":null,
            "ip_addr":null,
            "button_press_time":null,
            "last_keep_alive":null
        }
  }
```

My post method looks like the following one :

```
id params = @{@"name": @"Tinder",
              @"mobile":@"20934920",
              @"dob":@"1989-12-12",
              @"medications":@"pills",
              @"medical_conditions":@"lkas",
              @"watch":
                  @{
                      @"phonewatchno":@"239847239",
                      @"latitude":@"-33.99",
                      @"longitude":@"151.11",
                      @"gmaps":@"",
                      @"battery_life":@"",
                      @"last_update_time":@"",
                      @"location":@"",
                      @"short_imei":@"",
                      @"rssi":@"",
                      @"charging_status":@"",
                      @"voltage":@"",
                      @"network":@"",
                      @"altitude":@"",
                      @"ip_addr":@"",
                      @"button_press_time":@"",
                      @"last_keep_alive":@""

                    }

              };


    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescr= [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider myMapping]  method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/myPath.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addResponseDescriptor:responseDescr];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]HTTPClient]postPath:@"/myPath.json" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Mapped object %@",responseObject);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
    NSLog(@"An error occuered: %@",error);
}];

}
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT 1:

```
NSEntityDescription *watchEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Watches" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

Watches *watch = [[Watches alloc]initWithEntity:watchEntityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
watch.phonewatchno = [NSNumber numberWithInt:124512];
watch.latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:-33.99];
watch.longitude  = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:151.11];
watch.location = @"test location";
watch.gmaps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12];
watch.battery_life = [NSNumber numberWithInt:78];
watch.last_update_time = [NSDate date];
watch.last_keep_alive = [NSDate date];
watch.short_imei = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1233];
watch.rssi  = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
watch.charging_status = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
watch.voltage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:200];
watch.network = @"WIFI";
watch.altitude = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
watch.ip_addr = @"196.12.12.04";
watch.button_press_time = [NSNumber numberWithInt:4];

NSEntityDescription *wearersEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Wearers" inManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

Wearers *wearer = [[Wearers alloc]initWithEntity:wearersEntityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]managedObjectStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
wearer.name =@"test";
wearer.mobile = @"109283190";
wearer.medical_conditions = @"test";
wearer.medications = @"test";
wearer.dob = [NSDate date];
wearer.watches = [NSSet setWithObject:watch];

 RKEntityMapping *watchesMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Watches" inManagedObjectStore:[[EdisseDateModel sharedDataModel]objectStore]];
[watchesMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                              @"id": @"watch_id",
                                              @"altitude":@"altitude",
                                              @"battery_life":@"battery_life",
                                              @"button_press_time":@"button_press_time",
                                              @"charging_status":@"charging_status",
                                              @"gmaps":@"gmaps",
                                              @"ip_addr":@"ip_addr",
                                              @"last_keep_alive":@"last_keep_alive",
                                              @"last_update_time":@"last_update_time",
                                              @"latitude":@"latitude",
                                              @"longitude":@"longitude",
                                              @"location":@"location",
                                              @"network":@"network",
                                              @"phonewatchno":@"phonewatchno",
                                              @"rssi":@"rssi",
                                              @"short_imei":@"short_imei",
                                              @"updated_at":@"updated_at",
                                              @"voltage":@"voltage",
                                              @"wearer_id":@"wearer_id",
                                              @"updated_at":@"updated_at",



                                              }


 ];

[watchesMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"wearer" connectedBy:@{
                                                              @"wearer_id":@"wearer_id"
                                                              }];
[watchesMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"watch_id"]];


RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescr = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:watchesMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/watches.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];



[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addResponseDescriptor:responseDescr];


RKEntityMapping *wearersMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Wearers" inManagedObjectStore:[[EdisseDateModel sharedDataModel] objectStore]];

[wearersMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id":@"wearer_id",
                                              @"at_risk": @"at_risk",
                                              @"created_at": @"created_at",
                                              @"dob": @"dob",
                                              @"geo_radius": @"geo_radius",
                                              @"medical_conditions":@"medical_conditions",
                                              @"medications":@"medications",
                                              @"mobile":@"mobile",
                                              @"name":@"name",
                                              @"status":@"status",
                                              @"updated_at":@"updated_at",
                                              @"wearer_photo_content_type":@"wearer_photo_content_type",
                                              @"wearer_photo_file_size":@"wearer_photo_file_size",
                                              @"wearer_photo_file_name":@"wearer_photo_file_name",

                                              }
 ];
    wearersMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"wearer_id"];

[wearersMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"watch" toKeyPath:@"watches" withMapping:watchesMapping]];




RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:wearersMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:@"/wearers.json" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];



RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[wearersMapping inverseMapping]  objectClass:[Wearers class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST ];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"application/json"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]postObject:wearer path:@"/wearers.json" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{
    NSLog(@"Response : %@",mappingResult.array);
}
failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.userInfo.description);
}];
```

Now I'm getting error from failure block in my Xcode console like below :

```
Error: {
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey = "<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x178210760> { URL: https://www.test.com/wearers.json }";
AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey = "<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170421be0> { URL: https://www.test.com/wearers.json } { status code: 500, headers {\n    Connection = \"keep-alive\";\n    \"Content-Length\" = 48;\n    \"Content-Type\" = \"application/json; charset=utf-8\";\n    Date = \"Fri, 06 Jun 2014 03:43:59 GMT\";\n    Server = \"nginx/1.6.0 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.42\";\n    Status = \"500 Internal Server Error\";\n    \"X-Powered-By\" = \"Phusion Passenger 4.0.42\";\n    \"X-Request-Id\" = \"6ce273e7-4130-47c3-91de-8020db49426a\";\n    \"X-Runtime\" = \"0.011948\";\n} }";
NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://www.test.com/wearers.json";
NSLocalizedDescription = "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500";
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "{\"status\":\"500\",\"error\":\"Internal Server Error\"}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a request descriptor against `NSDictionary` and then not use the `HTTPClient` to action the post, just use the object manager (because the client knows nothing about request or response descriptors).

---

Following your edit your server is throwing an error - check the server log. Your code now looks ok for sending wearers with nested watches and receiving watches and connecting them by foreign key mapping. You need to check exactly what is sent with Charles against what the server is expecting.

Comment: can you take a look on my updated code now? I still fighting with my post request :/

Comment: Wain you were right that was problem on the server side. Thanks again my RestKit guru :)